# Display image from ajax json response in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, mysqli

I'm using the following code to display and then edit a record (by id) from a database in a Bootstrap modal however I can't seem to render the image of the record being edited. Everything else is working fine.

Is there something missing from my code for the base64 to work correctly? Or is the the  tag that needs editing? A HTML dataType renders the image fine...but I need the response in json format.

```
<div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal fade">  
  <div class="modal-dialog">  
       <div class="modal-content">  
            <div class="modal-header">  
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                 <h4 class="modal-title">PHP Ajax Update MySQL Data Through Bootstrap Modal</h4>  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-body">  
                 <form method="post" id="insert_form">  
                      <img src="image" name="image" id="image" />
                      <label>Enter Employee Name</label>  
                      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />  
                      <br />  
                      <label>Enter Employee Address</label>  
                      <textarea name="address" id="address" class="form-control"></textarea>  
                      <br />  
                      <label>Select Gender</label>  
                      <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control">  
                           <option value="Male">Male</option>  
                           <option value="Female">Female</option>  
                      </select>  
                      <br />  
                      <label>Enter Designation</label>  
                      <input type="text" name="designation" id="designation" class="form-control" />  
                      <br />  
                      <label>Enter Age</label>  
                      <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" />  
                      <br />  
                      <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" />  
                      <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />  
                 </form>  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-footer">  
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
            </div>  
       </div>  
  </div>  
 </div>  

HERE IS JQUERY AJAX CALL TO PASS THE DATA:-

<script>  
     $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           $('#insert').val("Insert");  
           $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"fetch.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#name').val(data.name);  
                     $('#address').val(data.address);  
                     $('#gender').val(data.gender);  
                     $('#designation').val(data.designation);  
                     $('#age').val(data.age);  
                     $('#employee_id').val(data.id);
                     $('#image').html(data.'<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + img  + '" />');  
                     $('#insert').val("Update");  
                     $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
                }  
           });  
      });
```

Fetch code

```
<?php  
//fetch.php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");   
if(isset($_POST["employee_id"]))  
{  
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee WHERE id = '".$_POST  ["employee_id"]."'";  
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
  echo json_encode($row);  
}  
?>
```

Comment: you need to show as code from fetch.php, probably you need to echo json_encode($dataFromBaze)

Comment: can you see in "network" response from ajax? is there anything, error or something?

Comment: I don't think there are any errors? Can't test it right now...It looks like it might be $('#image').html(data.'<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + img  + '" />'); that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the html property of an image tag to an image tag. This makes no sense at all. If it were to work, you would end up with something like:

```
<img><img src="..."></img>
```

Instead, just update to src of your existing image tag like this:

```
$('#image').attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,'+data.img);
```

Comment: ah...thanks. My mistake...I'll give it a go tonight.